# Continue not working properly

Tags: apex, batch, dml, update

I have below code where I do a check if a list value is contained in a set then jump to next iteration without executing the next statement that is update. Here I am using 'continue;' statement in else condition which is not working properly. Can someone suggest a way out please?

code:

```
global class AckCallUpdatenew implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Account_vod__c,Call_Date_vod__c,ESR_Call__c,Unlock_vod__c 
                        FROM Call2_vod__c 
                        WHERE ESR_Call__c=null 
                        AND Recordtype.Name LIKE \'%Sample%\' 
                        AND Status_vod__c = \'Submitted_vod\'';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Call2_vod__c> scope) {

    List<Call2_vod__c> AckCall= 
            [SELECT  Ack_For_Call_abv__c  
                      FROM Call2_vod__c
                     where  recordtype.Name like '%Acknowledge%']; 
    Set<string> s1 = new Set<string>();  

      for(Call2_Vod__c record:AckCall) {
                s1.add(record.Ack_For_Call_abv__c);
                }           
      for(Call2_vod__c a : scope)
      {
           If(!s1.contains(a.Name))
           {
                  if(a.ESR_Call__c==false && a.Call_Date_vod__c+90<date.today())
                   {
                    a.Unlock_vod__c=true;
                    a.ESR_Call__c=true;
                   // a.Status_vod__c='Saved_vod';
                    }
            }

            else continue;      // iterate to the next item in the loop

            update a;
       }

    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code to follow best practices. Why? Your code is prone to exceeding [governor limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm). Couple of suggestions to do so:

1. Use a list of SObject to support bulk update, like in your case declare `List <Call2_vod__c>` outside the loop (an **array** of SObject will work equally well).
2. **add** the item `a` to the list of SObject you declared in step-1, inside the `if{...}` statement when you are iterating over the **scope**.
3. I don't see any need for a `continue` now. So, you may comment/remove it (as required).
4. `Update` the list SObject outside of `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the update inside the if block so there is no need for the else block and continue but this is not a best practise .

So you can add the records to a list and update it outside the for loop.